# Techniques for Data Aging

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, architecture

I'm looking for information about how to age data in a db, generally related to Oracle and Sql 
  Server, but any database would be good. Any examples or books containing examples of how the best 
  techniques would be cool.

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, partitioning is a very useful for implementing Information Life-cycle Management, this enables you to manage data partition wise and store recent, most accessed data on quicker storage and older data, most of the times less often accessed on cheaper storage.
IF this is what you are trying to do, take a look at partitioning. In 11g: interval partitioning, takes out having to pre configure partitions; partitions are now created on as needed basis and reference partitioning. This is also a performance booster because it is now easier to do partition wise joins using PQ. It also saves space because the redundant key information is now in the partition definition.

Answer (score 2):

This whitepaper: [Strategies for Partitioning Relational Data Warehouses in Microsoft SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966457.aspx) has a chapter on Data Aging with a sliding window implementation.